# Dynamically set SignalR Hub name

Tags: c#, signalr

From what I gather from SignalR's documentation, a Hub's name is defined by either its derived class name, or by the `HubName` attribute.

Is there a way to configure a Hub name dynamically?

Comment: Can you expand your questions? What is your use case, what are you trying to achieve, can you post some code? Do you want "dynamic" hubs on the server side? Or on the client you want to dynamical decide which hub to use?

Comment: I dont like the idea that the hubs identifier (which is basically a string) is hard-coded in my code and I'de like it to be managed externally

Comment: What do you mean on "managed externally"? In a config file or with a static class, etc?

Comment: Yes some sort of an external config store

Comment: Then I think you will need a custom implementation of the `IHubDescriptorProvider` interface... you can check the default implementation on [Github.](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs)

Comment: You seems to like "configuration over convention" :)

Comment: Doesn't the hubname and client javascript code hand in hand? If so, it might not be much useful even if it was being driven by a config as this is not something that you would like to change at runtime without updating other pieces of code accessing it (although technically you could as other side is javascript).

Comment: I use SignalR to communicate between two c# applications, and having both of them write this const string... well it just doesnt feel right.